# Sequence of tenses. Present Perfect + Present or Past Simple (not reported speech)

Tags: present-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

we have a question:

**Have you ever felt like you miss someone you don’t even know?**

and we have an answer, which seems a bit confusing to me

*I suppose, that I *haven’t felt* I **miss** someone who I ***don’t know**.**

**or this one would be better and more correct?**

*I suppose, that I *haven’t felt* I missED someone who I *DIDN'T know**

Comment: So far as I can see, the additional element ***who I don’t/didn't know*** is just an irrelevant distraction.  I can't see any reason to prefer one over the other with, say, *Have you ever felt like you **understand / understood** calculus?*, nor can I see any meaningful difference between the possible replies *No I haven't felt that I **understand / understood** calculus* (it's quite natural in such contexts to "backshift" ***understood*** to match Past Tense ***haven't felt***, even if the speaker still doesn't understand at time of utterance).

Answer (score 1):

Q

> Have you ever felt like you miss someone you don’t even know?

I replace the relative pronoun 'who' with 'whom', thus

A1

> I suppose, that I haven’t felt I miss someone [whom] I don’t know.

A2

> I suppose, that I haven’t felt I missED someone [whom] I DIDN'T know[.]

Q is in present tense; A1 is consistent with it and fine.   Currently you do not miss anyone you do not know.

A2 means as of now, you have not felt you have in the past missed someone you did not know.  Whether you currently miss anyone you do not know is not mentioned.